# Where to place libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll for Android application Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, openssl, firemonkey

I am using Fire Monkey to develop a crossplatform app in Delphi RAD Studio 11. I am using OpenSSL libraries, on the windows version I placed the  libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll into my project /win32/debug folder in order to make OpenSSL work. For the Android version I've tried doing the same (Android/Debug)but I keep getting "Could not load SSL library" exception.

Is there an extra step that I am missing?

Thank you so much

Comment: DLLs are for Windows only.

Comment: Acording to [Delphi OpenSSL documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/OpenSSL) Android no longer uses OpenSSL since Android 6

Comment: Use .so files on Android. Also, you may need to use Indy's `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function to tell Indy where the `.so` files are located.

Comment: @SilverWarior it is true that Android itself no longer uses OpenSSL, in favor off Google's BoringSSL fork. Apps can deploy their own local copy of OpenSSL, but it is kind of hit-or-miss whether doing so will actually work nowadays. On some devices, it works fine. On other devices, it doesn't, because BoringSSL can interfer with OpenSSL.

Comment: I found out that I need to build the ssl libraries for android.  
 Is this what it should be done? https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android . This commands need to be ran in a linux terminal?

Comment: @MiguelMar there are some (slightly older) precompiled files for Android at https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries

Comment: Stop Indy and use `THTTPClient`, you will be able to call https api without configure anything

Comment: @Bosshoss Why are you assuming that OP is using OpenSSL for securing only HTTP protocol? What if he is using it for securing File Transfer Protocol (FTPS)? Or perhaps OP is using OpenSSL as a way to secure data of some other custom protocol.

Comment: I am using OpenSSL in order to connect to a MQTT Cloud Broker.  SSL is required in order to have a succesful connection.